# Barcode Scanner para iOS, Android e Windows Phone (PhoneGap)

Tags: apache-cordova, código-de-barras, scanner

Bom dia,
Há meses que procuro um plugin ou função que me permita fazer o scan de um código de barras através da minha app desenvolvida em PhoneGap para iOS, Android e Windows Phone. Alguém sabe de um plugin ou tutorial que realmente funcione?

Preciso mesmo de ajuda com isto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui finalmente fazer funcionar nos três sistemas operativos com a ajuda [deste tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/scanning-qr-code-cordova/). O projecto final foi o que me ajudou mais, para quem possa estar com o mesmo problema, podem encontrá-lo [aqui](https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/Cordova-QR-Code-Reader).

Answer (score 1):

Existe um post no proprio site do `phonegap` que mostra alguns plugins muito uteis, e felizmente um deles é o que você precisa!
Você pode encontrar o link [acessando esta pagina.](http://phonegap.com/blog/build/barcodescanner-plugin/) ou indo até o repositorio que [lista plugins uteis oficial do `phonegap`](https://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/11/07/cordova-plugins-put-them-in-your-own-repo-2/)

O item numero 1 da lista é o própria API para barcodescanner.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner

Ou você pode usar este também;

https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, Rafael, mas mesmo com esses links, que já conhecia, não consegui fazer funcionar. Mas consegui finalmente com a ajuda do tutorial que partilho na minha resposta.